# find_if error: invalid initialisation of reference of type 'const node&' from expression of type 'node*'

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, function-pointers

I have a struct node:

```
struct node {
    node *parent;
    int x, y;
    float f, g, h;
    };
```

I define a predicate condition bool function as follows to find whether a struct member already exists in the vector or not.

```
bool Isinit(const node &nm, const node &ref)
{
  if(nm.x==ref.x && nm.y==ref.y)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}
```

Then i call the fucntion thus:

```
vector<node*>::iterator referIt=find_if (open.begin(), open.end(), Isinit);
```

An error is reported:
invalid initialisation of reference of type 'const node&' from expression of type 'node*'. Can someone explain the error to me?

Comment: `if (…) return true; else return false;` is a terrible anti-pattern. Write `return …;` instead, it’s logically equivalent, and more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with your code: both in number of arguments and argument type:

```
vector<node*>::iterator referIt = 
    find_if (open.begin(), open.end(), Isinit);

bool Isinit(const node &nm, const node &ref);
```

`find_if` takes a *unary* predicate. It will call it on every element until it finds an element for which the predicate returns true. That predicate has to accept *one* argument of the type that is in the container. From your call to `find_if`, that type is `node*`. Thus, your signature must be:

```
bool Isinit(const node* nm);
```

Now that probably won't satisfy what it is you want to do, since you're looking for a `node*` to match your `ref`, so for that you would need to write a functor:

```
struct Isinit {
    const node* ref;

    Isinit(const node*);
    bool operator()(const node* nm); // compare passed-in 'nm'
                                     // against member 'ref'
};
```

And call thusly:

```
vector<node*>::iterator referIt = 
    find_if (open.begin(), open.end(), Isinit(ref));
```

Which, with C++11 lambdas, can all be done in-line:

```
auto referIt = find_if(open.begin(), open.end(), [ref](const node* nm){
    return nm->x == ref->x && nm->y == ref->y;
});
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the functor approach? A functor has a  constructor and overloaded operator as i know. So how have you defined the constructor here? And how will you return a `node*`using this approach?

Comment: @userzizzy A functor is just anything with an `operator()`. I didn't define the constructor - but it should just take a `node*` and assign the member `ref` to it. There is no returning of a `node*` - it should return `bool`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible implementation of `find_if` from [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find):

```
template<class InputIt, class UnaryPredicate>
InputIt find_if(InputIt first, InputIt last, UnaryPredicate p)
{
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
        if (p(*first)) {
            return first;
        }
    }
    return last;
}
```

It seems like you have a `vector` of `node*`, thus, when you iterate and dereference the iterators, what you pass to `p` is a `node*` but not a `node&` element. You can change your function to accept pointers to fix this issue. Also, see that `find_if` implementation accepts `UnaryPredicate p`, thus you cannot pass it a function accepting two arguments.

Edit:

Another `C++11` way to solve this problem is to use `bind` from `functional` header and bind the `ref` to `Isinit` as:

```
using namespace std::placeholders;
auto referIt = find_if (open.begin(), open.end(), std::bind(Isinit, _1, &ref));
```

Comment: Do you mean: `bool Isinit(const node* nm, const node* ref)`? That gives `error: too few arguments to function`.

Comment: correct, but `find_if` also needs a unary predicate not binary, so you cannot pass two things into it this way. It should be `bool Isinit(const node *nm)`.